# Do I need a towel in saunas in Germany?

Tags: germany, regulations, towels

There is always a problem: what to take with, and what would be provided on place?

How it is with towels in saunas in Germany? Do you have to take a sauna towel with you? Or the  towel is rented in price? Or maybe you don't need any towel inside sauna, and outside you can use your own towel, which don't have to be full size (for example, 80x60 would be enough)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A towel is required. And it has to be large enough. You are supposed to sit or to lie on it. One towel can be enough. However, a second towel and/or a bathrobe can be useful too, when you are relaxing outside the sauna. In most of the saunas you can rent towels and bathrobes.

If 80x60 refer to centimeters, than it's not enough. You have to fit on the towel, as shown here:

[image: How to sit in a sauna]

---

However, sitting like this won't be accepted. You will then be kindly reminded to put your feet on the towel:

[image: How not to sit in a sauna]

Comment: What is the minimal size, then? 80x60 is fully enough to sit on...

Comment: @ŁukaszLech Maybe your butt fits on that, but where will you put your feet?

Comment: Interesting. In Tbilisi no towels in sauna were allowed. And in Germany you are not allowed to touch with your feed the desks? As I see, at least the towel doesn't have to be white.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech Well, in dry saunas the towels is compulsory. But in steam baths it is not requited, sometimes even forbidden. Anyway, not a good idea to take a towel into a steam bath ...

Comment: Hmmm OK. Good to know.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech You can read the following. It explains pretty good how it works http://www.visitsauna.fi/en/sauna/sauna-culture/visiting-a-german-sauna

Comment: Don't touch anything with your skin, be always dry... rules, rules and rules, difficult to follow... at least, is there any tolerance and guidance for novices, or just a deep water culture shock?

Comment: Germany is full of rules. Rules are ruling there! But don't worry, if you are missing a rule, you will be kindly reminded. Somebody will tell you, for sure. Don't take this as an offense. You can also ask the "Saunameister". If you are a novice, they will be glad to show you around.

Comment: In what land do you live? It can be very regionalized...

Comment: What country is the second photo from?

Comment: This answer is correct, you would need a towel, at least just to sit or lie on it and not burn your buttocks. Concerning putting your feet on the towel -- I don't know where this rule come from, but I live **in Berlin in Germany (though I've also been in the sauna in Brandenburg, München, Stuttgart)** and never had to put my feet on the towel... so I would say 80x60 is more than enough.

Comment: @Alex: maybe there is a misunderstanding, or people just politely ignored your faux pas. The rule is often posted as "no sweat on the wood". If you sit on the bottom bench and put your feet on the floor, that would be fine. But if you sit higher and put your feet on the lower benches, there should be a towel underneath.

Answer (score 6):

Most places have a policy requiring towels and also a rule with says "no sweat on the wood". You will need to have a towel big enough to cover the area to sit and for your feet. Just make sure that wherever you might drop sweat its covered by your towel. No one will measure your towel, just stick to this rule.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the second part of the question: Saunas often provide towels and bathrobes (the latter might be mandatory in the bar/restaurant area, when there is one) but I have never seen them included in the entry price. Often, the sauna *sells* towels (as opposed to lending/renting them). In any case, it would always cost something on top of the regular price and most guests prefer to bring their own.